# previous friday of month

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, select

I am trying to write a query that will return the last friday of the previous month  This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT sysdate
FROM   DUAL
where (LAST_DAY( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         'Friday' );
```

Comment: If you try to **return** something, it shouldn't be in the `where` clause of your query (that, quite apart from the correct functions to use for this, and the correct calculation). Putting that in the `where` clause suggests that you have difficulty with the most basic elements of SQL queries; try to focus more on those for now, and only then move on to more advanced topics.

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
select next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'month') - interval '8' day, 'Friday') from dual
```

Rationale:

- `trunc(sysdate, 'month')` gives you the first day of the current month
- we offset that value by 8 days so we can the the date 7 days before the end of the previous month
- then, `next_day()` returns the next Friday after this date, that is the last Friday of the month

Comment: I was about to post the same thing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: to me, that means I found the best possible solution (or very close to it)!

Comment: Is the argument to `next_day` always in English?

Comment: @wolφi from [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions118.htm#SQLRF00672) **The argument char must be a day of the week in the date language of your session**

Comment: @micklesh Just checked the very page but skipped over this sentence, sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT NEXT_DAY( LAST_DAY( TO_DATE('01-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MON-YYYY')) - 1 ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'FRIDAY' ) FROM DUAL;